# PHP - Replacing mcrypt_create_iv() with openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I need to up the security of our website, and is currently using the guide here: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm, and also the generation of random passwords here: https://defuse.ca/generating-random-passwords.htm. I gather that both uses the function `mcrypt_create_iv()` for generating random bytes (or bits?), but for some reason, I encounter errors in installing php-mcrypt under CentOS 6. Fortunately, the first link said that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is a CSPRNG (and the PHP documentation and other sources also back that claim), and is available on the current server installation of PHP 5.4, so I have no choice but to use that at the moment. With these in mind, I would like to ask the following:

1. Does a direct code substitution suffice without affecting security? (That is, just replacing calls to `mcrypt_create_iv()` to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` would do?)
2. About the constants mentioned in the code (http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing), the guide says that "[m]ake sure your salt is at least as long as the hash function's output." Am I right in assuming that `PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES` and `PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES` are both set to 24 bytes since the output of the `pbkdf2()` function would be just 24 bytes, not 32 (for 256 bits) since the underlying algorithm used is `sha256`? (Yes, I am using key stretching too.) In a related note, is 24 bytes fine, or should be increased/decreased, and what effect would that have?

Advanced thanks for those who will answer.

Comment: Also see [Upgrading my encryption library from Mcrypt to OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43329513/608639) and [Preparing for removal of Mcrypt in PHP 7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42696657/608639)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I think the security will not be affected because both functions are just cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generators (NB: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len, true)` and `mcrypt_create_iv($len, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM)`).
2. `PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES` is used only in the test function `create_hash()` and not in `pbkdf2()` itself. So you just need to implement your own salt generation function using those CSPRNGs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still would like to clarify something: Is 24 bytes fine, or should I increase it?

Comment: @shippou I'm not a crypto specialist but I think 24 symbols are hard to brute-force, according to [this](http://calc.opensecurityresearch.com/) calculator it will take about 358 sextillion years on a single computer (24 — HMAC MD5 — ualpha-numeric).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the link! I really don't know that site existed. Thanks for the referral. :)

Comment: Just a note that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len, &$crypto_strong = null)`

So passing in `true` as the second parameter does nothing but throw a warning 

It is there to indicate whether the cipher use is strong ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php))